# How to kill a script that has been executed using source?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The problem is that I cannot find the process ID of a script that has been executed using *source*. I am able to do so when they are launched with *bash* using `ps -ef`.

If I run a script using *bash*, I can figure the process ID using `ps -ef | grep "test1.sh" | grep -v "grep"`. However, if I run the script using *source*, I cannot search for it and hence cannot find the *process ID*.
I have read the difference between the bash and source commands from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306523/using-source-vs-bash-commands).

This is my testing procedure:
I have 2 terminals. In one of them, I am searching for process IDs using `ps -ef`. In the other one, I run a script which prints 'Hello' every one second (an infinite while loop with sleep of 1 second). With *bash*, PID is searchable, but with *source*, *grep* doesn't get any results.

I am working on an *Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS* machine

Comment: When you `source`, you are executing commands in the ***current*** shell. There will be no separate process.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hi, so how do it stop it from running? Will exiting work?

Comment: Yes, if you exit the current session, then you should kill it all. The question become whether there are separate processes created by the sourced commands that you could kill. You would have to know the name of the process you want to kill to find the correct PID. If you look at what you are sourcing -- can you pick out what you need to kill? If so, you can kill process by process. (at that point, exiting is probably easier ... )

Comment: If you store `$BASHPID` *before* the `source` operation, that remains the active PID *during* the `source` operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you do *not* want to terminate the sourcing `bash` and are satisfied with the script being stopped only after a command (such as `sleep`) finishes, you can `kill -INT` the `bash` process.